How do I defer reflection on a view/table without primary keys?
I have a view xyz.MyTable that I'd like to build a model for. It doesn't have a unique column but the combination of columns col1 and col2 are guaranteed to be unique.
I also don't have access to the engine at declaration, so I need to use deferred reflection. Here is my attempt:
import sqlalchemy
import sqlalchemy.ext.declarative

Base = sqlalchemy.orm.declarative_base()
class MyTable(sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.DeferredReflection, Base):
    __tablename__ = 'MyTable'
    __table__ = sqlalchemy.Table(__tablename__, Base.metadata, schema='xyz', autoload=True)
    __mapper_args__ = {'primary_key': [__table__.c.col1, __table__.c.col2]} 

However, this results in the following:

KeyError: 'col1'

This makes sense, because col1 can't be an object until reflection occurs. But how can I declare the primary key column? Note that I have no control over the database and cannot make any changes to the view.
Update:
As per python_user's suggestion I tried using strings for the column names:
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import Column
from sqlalchemy.types import DATE, INTEGER, VARCHAR

from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base, DeferredReflection

Base = declarative_base(cls=DeferredReflection)

class VHistSnapPnL(Base):
    __tablename__ = "MyTable"

    __mapper_args__ = {
        "primary_key": [
            'col1',
            'col2'
        ]
    }

Base.prepare(engine)

However this results in an AttributeError:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[10], line 6
      2 from sqlalchemy.ext.automap import automap_base
      4 # Base = automap_base()
      5 # reflect the tables
----> 6 Base.prepare(engine)

File /juno-tmp/virtualenvs/python3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/ext/declarative/extensions.py:400, in DeferredReflection.prepare(cls, engine)
    398 for thingy in to_map:
    399     cls._sa_decl_prepare(thingy.local_table, insp)
--> 400     thingy.map()
    401     mapper = thingy.cls.__mapper__
    402     metadata = mapper.class_.metadata

File /juno-tmp/virtualenvs/python3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/decl_base.py:1127, in _DeferredMapperConfig.map(self, mapper_kw)
   1125 def map(self, mapper_kw=util.EMPTY_DICT):
   1126     self._configs.pop(self._cls, None)
-> 1127     return super(_DeferredMapperConfig, self).map(mapper_kw)

File /juno-tmp/virtualenvs/python3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/decl_base.py:1047, in _ClassScanMapperConfig.map(self, mapper_kw)
   1042 else:
   1043     mapper_cls = mapper
   1045 return self.set_cls_attribute(
   1046     "__mapper__",
-> 1047     mapper_cls(self.cls, self.local_table, **self.mapper_args),
   1048 )

File <string>:2, in __init__(self, class_, local_table, properties, primary_key, non_primary, inherits, inherit_condition, inherit_foreign_keys, always_refresh, version_id_col, version_id_generator, polymorphic_on, _polymorphic_map, polymorphic_identity, concrete, with_polymorphic, polymorphic_load, allow_partial_pks, batch, column_prefix, include_properties, exclude_properties, passive_updates, passive_deletes, confirm_deleted_rows, eager_defaults, legacy_is_orphan, _compiled_cache_size)

File /juno-tmp/virtualenvs/python3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/deprecations.py:375, in deprecated_params.<locals>.decorate.<locals>.warned(fn, *args, **kwargs)
    368     if m in kwargs:
    369         _warn_with_version(
    370             messages[m],
    371             versions[m],
    372             version_warnings[m],
    373             stacklevel=3,
    374         )
--> 375 return fn(*args, **kwargs)

File /juno-tmp/virtualenvs/python3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py:693, in Mapper.__init__(self, class_, local_table, properties, primary_key, non_primary, inherits, inherit_condition, inherit_foreign_keys, always_refresh, version_id_col, version_id_generator, polymorphic_on, _polymorphic_map, polymorphic_identity, concrete, with_polymorphic, polymorphic_load, allow_partial_pks, batch, column_prefix, include_properties, exclude_properties, passive_updates, passive_deletes, confirm_deleted_rows, eager_defaults, legacy_is_orphan, _compiled_cache_size)
    691 self._configure_properties()
    692 self._configure_polymorphic_setter()
--> 693 self._configure_pks()
    694 self.registry._flag_new_mapper(self)
    695 self._log("constructed")

File /juno-tmp/virtualenvs/python3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py:1391, in Mapper._configure_pks(self)
   1389 if self._primary_key_argument:
   1390     for k in self._primary_key_argument:
-> 1391         if k.table not in self._pks_by_table:
   1392             self._pks_by_table[k.table] = util.OrderedSet()
   1393         self._pks_by_table[k.table].add(k)

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'table'


but you could insert the data in your own database, where you do have control over, and read in python from that database

you can just do 'primary_key': ['col1', 'col2']

@GuidoG that's not an option unfortunately

@python_user that resolves the error. When I now set autoload=True in the Table constructor I get UnboundExecutionError: No engine is bound to this Table's MetaData. Is it ok to leave autoload out? Will the table automatically reflect when an operation is performed with an engine?

will you ever have access to the engine?

Only when the user makes requests to the backend (the engine will use the user's credentials)

@python_user if I use strings I get AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'table' from /sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py:1393 when I call MyTable.prepare(engine) (because k, which is now a string, has no attribute called 'table'). So I don't think this works.

it works fine for me @quant, I created a view and I am able to query it, I don't think I see any k in the code, can you edit your question to have a more complete example?

@python_user see updates to the question.

what version are you on?

This works for me (SQLAlchemy 2.0.30)

@python_user 1.4.49

Interesting, so maybe it's a version issue. Will test with a newer version

Yep, works fine on sqlalchemy 2.0.20

From the changelog for SQLAlchemy 2.0.16 here:

Improved DeferredReflection.prepare() to accept arbitrary **kw arguments that are passed to MetaData.reflect(), allowing use cases such as reflection of views

So in SQLA 2.0.16 and later, a view like
CREATE VIEW team AS
SELECT 'AB' AS prov, 'Calgary' AS city, 'Flames' AS team_name
UNION ALL
SELECT 'AB' AS prov, 'Edmonton' AS city, 'Oilers' AS team_name

can be used with deferred reflection like this:
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, select
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import DeferredReflection
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase, Session


class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass


class Reflected(DeferredReflection):
    __abstract__ = True


class Team(Reflected, Base):
    __tablename__ = "team"  # name of the view
    __mapper_args__ = {"primary_key": ["prov", "city"]}


engine = create_engine("postgresql://scott:tiger@192.168.0.199/test")

Reflected.prepare(engine, views=True)

with Session(engine) as sess:
    home_team = sess.scalars(select(Team).where(Team.city == "Calgary")).one()
    print(home_team.team_name)  # Flames

For earlier versions of SQLAlchemy you will most likely have to omit deferred reflection and simply recreate the view structure in the ORM class, e.g., something like this
class Team(Base):
    __tablename__ = "team"  # name of the view
    prov = Column(String(5), primary_key=True)
    city = Column(String(25), primary_key=True)
    team_name = Column(String(25)

